# Wordpress - How to change thumbnail size on Homepage? Can't find reference

Tags: wordpress

I've searched throughout and can't find where to change the base thumbnail size on the Homepage (www.tomcpalead.com). It's set to 210 x 158. I change the Functions.php and nothing updates on the Homepage. Can't find the reference in style.css to edit it either.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: related to a deleted question of yours, sorry if i was short there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307643/view-comment-history-on-deleted-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your thumbnails seems to be coming from here:

http://tomcpalead.com/?custom-css=1&csblog=1&cscache=6&csrev=4

I haven't seen CSS files named like that before though, so I'll defer to others who will have a better idea of where that's coming from. If there's any setting somewhere in your theme that looks like the following then that is what I would try editing:

```
.river .thumb img{width:16rem;height:9.75rem}
```

Comment: Yeah it's a reference to something higher, inheriting it. Anyway I can override the existing CSS? If I use custom.css and insert the above code edited?

Comment: If you put !important on the end of your CSS declarations then it should override any others that point to it. So yes, give that a shot.

Comment: Love the effort ! Thank you. But unfortunately still outputting the same, can't even see the reference to the new CSS

Comment: Yes! I got it. Thank you so much Eaamonn. I'd upvote you but I can't.

Comment: Welcome. FYI, I don't know what browser you're using, but in Chrome you can right click on any element on the page and "Inspect Element." This will show you what its CSS styles are and where they're coming from.

Comment: Yeah I could see the reference, but didn't know as it came from 6+ styles. I didn't know how to override with !important either. Big help.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to wordpress admin and follow this path :

**Go to admin => Settings => Media**

here, you will get the thumbnail size for all the images defined. You can change it as per your choice.

After modifying size, just check it by uploading a new image and set it a thumbnail image.

Comment: It's currently set to 150 x 150. However the theme still outputs 210 x 158

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: yes you need to check the theme settings..if you found nothing like that there just go to your home page template of your theme and check the code, what is happening there..

Comment: I've checked the theme settings and nothing in relation to thumbnail

I've checked the homepage code and still it's confusing. Can you tell me which file to edit?